# Oracle SQL - Join with sub condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables in Oracle database: **items** (id, type, name) and **contracts** (id, item_id).

I want to select all items that is of type "sale" and have a contract OR all items that is of type "gift" (no matter contract here).

For this, I yped:

```
SELECT
  i.id,
  c.id as contract_id,
  i.type,
  i.name
FROM
  items i,
  contracts c,
  -- others table
WHERE
  -- some implicit joins
  AND (
    (i.type = 'sale' AND c.item_id = i.id) OR
    (i.type = 'gift')
  )
```

This doesn't work.

How to select products of type "sale" and "gift" and join contracts only if type is "sale"?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. And take a look at [mcve] too.

Comment: Not at all surprised it doesn't work, given that `p` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query does not work because you are using an INNER JOIN (although with an archaic syntax).
So your 2nd condition:

> OR all items that is of type "gift" (no matter contract here)

cannot be applied because the INNER JOIN removes the rows from items that do not have any contract.
Use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
select 
  i.id,
  c.id as contract_id,
  i.type,
  i.name
from items i left join contracts c
on c.item_id = i.id
where 
    (i.type = 'sale' AND c.item_id is not null) 
    OR
    (i.type = 'gift')
```

Comment: Perfect! that is the exact tip I was looking for.